# Listing phone contacts using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, cordova, mobile, contacts

Im developing a multi-platform app for android, ios and windows using  simple html, css, js and condova however I find it challenging, as simple as it may sound, to display all the contacts that are on the device in a list, just as how you would find it in the phonebook or contacts app. Here is the design of the contact interface:

```
<?php
?>

<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
        <style type="text/css">
            a { 
                color: inherit;
                text-decoration: none;
            }

            #BODY {
                background-color: #D9D9D9;
            }

            #TABLE {
                width:100.0%;
                border-collapse:collapse;
                background-color: #3A59C0;
                position: fixed;
                top: 0px;
                margin-left: -8px;
            }

            #CONTACTLIST {
                width: 100%;
                height: 91%;
                margin-top: 53px;
                background-color: #D9D9D9;
                overflow-y: scroll; 
                overflow-x:hidden;
                position: fixed;
                list-style-type: none;
                margin-left: -50px;
            }

            #CONTACTLIST > li {
                border-top: 1px solid gray;
            }

            #CONTACTLIST span {
                margin-left: 15px;
                font-family: verdana;
                color: #535353;
                font-size: 1.6cm;
            }

        </style>
    </head>

    <body id="BODY">
        <table id="TABLE" >

            <tr style="height: 50px; width: 45px;">
                <td style="width: 45%;"><center><span style="font-family: verdana;  color: white;">Contacts</span></center></td>
            </tr>

            <tr style="height: 10px;  width: 45px;">
                <td style="width: 45%; background-color: #31C1FF;"></td>
                <td style="width: 45%;"></td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <ul id="CONTACTLIST"> 
            <li><span>"NAME"  "NUMBER"</span></li>
            <li><span>"NAME"  "NUMBER"</span></li>
            <li><span>"NAME"  "NUMBER"</span></li>
            <li><span>"NAME"  "NUMBER"</span></li>
            <li><span>"NAME"  "NUMBER"</span></li>
            <li><span>"NAME"  "NUMBER"</span></li>
            <li><span>"NAME"  "NUMBER"</span></li>
            <li><span>"NAME"  "NUMBER"</span></li>
            <li><span>"NAME"  "NUMBER"</span></li>
            <li><span>"NAME"  "NUMBER"</span></li>
            <li><span>"NAME"  "NUMBER"</span></li>
            <li><span>"NAME"  "NUMBER"</span></li>
            <li><span>"NAME"  "NUMBER"</span></li>
            <li><span>"NAME"  "NUMBER"</span></li>
            <li><span>"NAME"  "NUMBER"</span></li>
            <li><span>"NAME"  "NUMBER"</span></li>
            <li><span>"NAME"  "NUMBER"</span></li>
            <li><span>"NAME"  "NUMBER"</span></li>
            <li><span>"NAME"  "NUMBER"</span></li>
            <li><span>"NAME"  "NUMBER"</span></li>
        </ul>
    </body>
</html>
```

but instead of "NAME"  "NUMBER" the script would access the contact database and list out all contacts using the methods available in the cordova.js file, in alphabetical order.

Comment: So you want to know ow to get the contacts list ? Sorry but yor question is not very clear to me at the moment.

Comment: yes, just as how you would see it in the contact app

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From Cordova 3 [even “core” APIs](https://cordova.apache.org/blog/releases/2013/07/23/cordova-3.html) are outside of the core (cordova.js).

So you need to first install the [contacts plugin](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-contacts) and then add the [code for list them](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-contacts#example-1). If you want to only select a contact, you could use the [pick contact](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-contacts#navigatorcontactspickcontact) function, that opens the native contact picker and return the selected contact object.

#### Get all contacts from phone

```
function onSuccess(contacts) {
    console.log('Found ' + contacts.length + ' contacts.');
    // here you can manipulate the contacts array
    console.log(contacts);
};

function onError(contactError) {
    console.log('Error: '+contactError);
};

// list all contacts
var options      = new ContactFindOptions();
options.filter   = "";
options.multiple = true;
var fields = [navigator.contacts.fieldType.displayName, navigator.contacts.fieldType.name];
navigator.contacts.find(fields, onSuccess, onError, options);
```