# get contact list in JS

Tags: javascript, android, cordova

I want to get contact list from Android(If user open website in android). I was searching on it little bit. I found two question in stackoverflow similar to this.

1. [Obtain Contacts Permission before Navigating (Cordova)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35254613/obtain-contacts-permission-before-navigating-cordova)
2. [Listing phone contacts using javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32415504/listing-phone-contacts-using-javascript#32420633)
3. [Cordova](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/7.x/reference/cordova-plugin-contacts/#example)

Here what I tried.

```js
    function onSuccess(contacts) {
        alert('Found ' + contacts.length + ' contacts.');
    };
    
    function onError(contactError) {
        alert('onError!');
    };
    
    // find all contacts with 'Bob' in any name field
    var options      = new ContactFindOptions();
    options.filter   = "Bob";
    options.multiple = true;
    options.desiredFields = [navigator.contacts.fieldType.id];
    options.hasPhoneNumber = true;
    var fields       = [navigator.contacts.fieldType.displayName, navigator.contacts.fieldType.name];
    navigator.contacts.find(fields, onSuccess, onError, options);
```

I didn't get any error or alert message in android. When I visit the webpage in PC I got an error

> Uncaught ReferenceError: ContactFindOptions is not defined
> at contacts.php:17

I think I am having error cause, there's no contact function in PC.
I am so beginner in JS. I think [Cordova must be installed in PC](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/7.x/reference/cordova-plugin-contacts/#installation), I am not sure of the information also. If I have to than how can I install Cordova? I am using Debian Based Linux Distro. So, I tried

```
sudo apt-get install cordova
```

But,

> E: Unable to locate package cordova

Comment: Resolving this is most likely going to require more knowledge regarding how your project is set up. To start with, the installation command for cordova on Linux is `sudo npm install -g cordova`. This will install Cordova into your CLI globally via Node Package Manager.

Comment: @ChaseIngebritson I was going to run that command `sudo npm install -g cordova`. Suddenly I faced the issue https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/645526/unable-to-upgrade-or-fix-either

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you building a mobile app with Cordova or are you just running your code in a website on Android?

If it’s just a website: you simply can’t do what you want since the browser doesn’t provide an interface to the contact list.

Unlike a Cordova app, which has access to the system APIs, among them the contact list API, JavaScript Code executed in a mobile browser, cannot access such APIs. The browser JS API simply provides no way.

JavaScript code run inside a Cordova/Capacitor mobile app however can Cordova APIs which bridge the mobile’s native API to JavaScript.